# how to perform git operations with specified username/password?

Tags: git

I want to run script on a CI server which will automatically remove old branches from git repository. I have to pass git's username/password as parameters to this script because server is shared between different teams, so I can't, for example, store ssh key on a server. I can clone repository with provided credentials `git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`. 
But I can't perform any other operations, for example, `git push origin --delete branch_name` - the promt will ask for password.
Is there a way to provide credentials for git operation in my case via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Prompt will never ask for the password when you clone a repository with the following command.

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

please make sure your username and password are set in origin keyword.

```
git remote -v

origin  https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git (fetch)
origin  https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git (push)
```

If it is not present then try to change url

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

After that it won't ask for password

```
git push origin --delete branch_name
```